# How to Make Dynamic Colum Header on MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, database

I Have MYSQL query

```
SELECT a.`name` AS Picker, b.name AS 'Ecommerce Name',
CASE
    WHEN c.`pick_status` = 1 THEN "Hold Pick"
    WHEN c.`pick_status` = 2 THEN "Pending Pick"
    WHEN c.`pick_status` = 3 THEN "Confirm Pick"
    ELSE "Not Yet"
END AS 'Status Pick'
 , COUNT(c.`pick_status`) AS Total
    FROM 
        `users` a,
        `trx_order_ecommerce` c,
        `master_ecommerces` b
    WHERE 
        c.`picked_by` = a.`id` AND
        b.id = c.ecommerce_id
        AND c.picked_by = 84
     GROUP BY a.`name`, c.`pick_status`,  b.name;
```

Output

[image: Output]

I Want To Make Column as a Header Like This

[image]

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    a.name AS Picker,
    b.name AS 'Ecommerce Name',
    SUM(c.pick_status = 1) AS "Hold Pick",
    SUM(c.pick_status = 2) AS "Pending Pick",
    SUM(c.pick_status = 3) AS "Confirm Pick"
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN trx_order_ecommerce c ON c.picked_by = a.id
LEFT JOIN master_ecommerces b ON b.id = c.ecommerce_id AND c.picked_by = 84
GROUP BY
    a.name,
    b.name;
```